# How to allow dynamic column space to data in css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to create a 3 parent div : A B C, every parent have a grid system as a child, and when I get A1 from server I must put it into A column, B1 into B and so on, but when I get more than 3 children in same column I should create another column inside parent, I'm trying with css grid but I don't know how to achive this mechanism.
this is what I've tried :

```css
.children {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <span style="background: orange;">A</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span style="background: red;">B</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B2</div>
      <div>B3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span style="background: green;">C</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>C1</div>
      <div>C2</div>
      <div>C3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result is this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrWoQ.png)

And when I add A4 for example, it should be like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo9Fs.png)

As you can see, the width of A column has changed since we get 4 elements, I want the same mechanism in all columns A B C.
Have you an idea how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please update with the CSS you have so we may best assist you here..  You say "grid" but are using "flex".

Comment: I just edit my question, please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

Add any additional column inside the `additional-cols` div, here is an example:

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9jwvhv?file=index.html)

Another solution is to repeat children with 2 columns by 1 frame:

```
.children {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

Here is [another example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9jwvhv?file=index.html) on Stackblitz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
    .parent {
        display: flex;
    }
    .children {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
    <div>
        <span style="background: orange;">A</span>
        <div class="children">
        <div>A1</div>
        <div>A2</div>
        <div>A3</div>
        <div>A3</div>
        <div>A3</div>
        <div>A3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="background: red;">B</span>
        <div class="children">
        <div>B1</div>
        <div>B2</div>
        <div>B3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span style="background: green;">C</span>
        <div class="children">
        <div>C1</div>
        <div>C2</div>
        <div>C3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not work, it divide the parent container to a fixed row dimensions..

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check it up!

Comment: Use JavaScript to add columns inside `additional-cols` div if it contain more than three div's, for example: `var checkMainDivsLength = document.querySelector('.main-cols').children.length; // Do if statement to add any other column inside additional-cols if checkMainDivsLength >= 3`

Comment: How can I achiev it without changing my html bloc ? I want to have only children in my blocs, without additionnals cols divs..

Comment: not work when I add A4 and B4 ..

Answer (score 0):

Some grids within grids; how another div (D) would appear is controlled by the first grid - so like I have it here it would wrap below these three for example as does the A4 when added - just change the first grid column width to get it to NOT do so;

```css
body,
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* super center our parent in our view */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  /* the 8em is the width of each A B C block so with 8em we get space on children */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
  background-color: #00FFFF10;
}

.parent>* {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 2em 1fr;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: start;
}

.children {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5em;
  align-items: start;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}

.children>* {
  border: solid 1px #00FF0B;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <span style="background: orange;">A</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A3</div>
      <div>A4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span style="background: red;">B</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B2</div>
      <div>B3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span style="background: green;">C</span>
    <div class="children">
      <div>C1</div>
      <div>C2</div>
      <div>C3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a display column, not rows..

Comment: I edited it but you can work on how you want the A4 etc to display